# Displaying Strings and stopping write in text box Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textbox

Ok, so I am writing a basic Mp3 player program. I need it to do the following and I am having a little trouble.
First I have the buttons and the GUI sorta the way I want, functionality comes first. I need to be able to display the strings that I enter in my text fields under artist/album/track to show up in a list box on the left hand side.... so maybe I can post a bit of my code and someone could give me an example of how i could get it to work....
Could someone show me an example of how exactly I connect the input from the user and display in the GUI...the first code shown here is the manager program, the second part is the mp3 program that handles the input from the user...sorry I know it's a lot. I appreciate the help. Thanks.

```
private JButton addMP3Button, displayMP3sButton, findMP3Button, deleteMP3Button, 
                albumButton, artistButton, songButton, lengthButton;            
private JLabel artistLabel, songLabel, albumLabel, trackLengthLabel;
private JTextField artistField, songField, albumField, trackLengthField;
private JPanel buttonPanel, fieldPanelArtist, fieldPanelSong,
                fieldPanelAlbum, fieldPanelTrackLength;
{


    artistLabel = new JLabel("Artist Name ");
    artistField = new JTextField(20);


    fieldPanelArtist = new JPanel();
    fieldPanelArtist.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fieldPanelArtist.add(artistLabel);
    fieldPanelArtist.add(artistField);

    songLabel = new JLabel("Song Title ");
    songField = new JTextField(20);

    fieldPanelSong = new JPanel();
    fieldPanelSong.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fieldPanelSong.add(songLabel);
    fieldPanelSong.add(songField);

    albumLabel = new JLabel("Album Name ");
    albumField = new JTextField(20);

    fieldPanelAlbum = new JPanel();
    fieldPanelAlbum.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fieldPanelAlbum.add(albumLabel);
    fieldPanelAlbum.add(albumField);

    trackLengthLabel = new JLabel("Track Length (in seconds) ");
    trackLengthField = new JTextField(20);

    fieldPanelTrackLength = new JPanel();
    fieldPanelTrackLength.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    fieldPanelTrackLength.add(trackLengthLabel);
    fieldPanelTrackLength.add(trackLengthField);


    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 200 ) );
    //setPreferredSize( );
    inputPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 5, 5));
    inputPanel.add(fieldPanelArtist);
    inputPanel.add(fieldPanelSong);
    inputPanel.add(fieldPanelAlbum);
    inputPanel.add(fieldPanelTrackLength);


    //add mp3 file to the text field
    addMP3Button = new JButton(" Add MP3 ");

    //display the list of mp3 files already loaded
    displayMP3sButton = new JButton("Display MP3s");
    //find a certain mp3 file based on key word
    findMP3Button = new JButton(" Find MP3 ");
    //delete a file from the list
    deleteMP3Button = new JButton("Delete MP3");


    //sort functions here
    albumButton = new JButton(" Album ");
    //sort by album-alphabetical
    artistButton = new JButton(" Artist ");
    //sort by artist- alphabetical
    songButton = new JButton(" Song ");
    //songs
    lengthButton = new JButton(" Length ");
    //longest track


    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 2, 2));
    buttonPanel.add(addMP3Button);
    buttonPanel.add(displayMP3sButton);
    buttonPanel.add(findMP3Button);
    buttonPanel.add(deleteMP3Button);
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 50 ) );

    JPanel sortPanel = new JPanel();
    sortPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 2, 2));
    sortPanel.add(artistButton);
    sortPanel.add(albumButton);
    sortPanel.add(songButton);
    sortPanel.add(lengthButton);
    sortPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 50 ) );


    JPanel RightPanel = new JPanel();
    RightPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout( FlowLayout.RIGHT, 2, 2 ));

    RightPanel.add(inputPanel); 
    RightPanel.add(buttonPanel); 



    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(12, 20);
    textArea.setLineWrap(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);


    JPanel LeftPanel = new JPanel();
    LeftPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 2, 2));
    LeftPanel.add(textArea);
    LeftPanel.add(sortPanel);
    LeftPanel.add(scrollPane);
    textArea.setVisible(true);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();

    Container container = getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
    container.add(LeftPanel);
    container.add(RightPanel);




    //add(container, BorderLayout.NORTH );

    //JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    //add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    addMP3Button.addActionListener(this);

    displayMP3sButton.addActionListener(this);

    findMP3Button.addActionListener(this);

    deleteMP3Button.addActionListener(this);



}

private String artist;
private String song;
private String album;
private int trackLength;

public Mp3(String artistName, String songName, String albumName,
        int trackLeng) {
    setArtist(artistName);
    setSong(songName);
    setAlbum(albumName);
    setTrackLength(trackLeng);
}

public void setArtist(String artistName) {
    artist = artistName;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public void setSong(String songName) {
    song = songName;
}

public String getSong() {
    return song;
}

public void setAlbum(String albumName) {
    album = albumName;
}

public String getAlbum() {
    return album;
}

public void setTrackLength(int trackLeng) {
   trackLength = (trackLeng > 0) ? trackLeng : 5 ;
}

public int getTrackLength() {
    return trackLength;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %d : %d", getArtist(), getSong(),
            getAlbum(), getTrackLength() / 60, getTrackLength() % 60);
}
```

}

Comment: Start with the Swing tutorials and this awesome list of all-things Swing: [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)

Comment: *"...write in text box JAVA GUI"* What is a `text box`? *"I need to be able to display the strings that I enter in my text fields under artist/album/track to show up in a list box"*. What is a `list box.` I'm not aware of those classes. Use proper terminology when asking a question. Sometimes we can guess what you mean. Sometimes we can't.